# RMI client deployed on weblogic get ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, weblogic, classloader

here is the exception I get :

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xyz.ServiceFactory.getAppName(ServiceFactory.java:190)
    at com.xyz.ServiceFactory.getApplicationName(ServiceFactory.java:128)
    at com.xyz.SomeServiceAccessorProxy.<init>(SomeServiceAccessorProxy.java:10)
    at com.xyz.SomeServiceAccessorImpl.getService(SomeServiceAccessorImpl.java:41)
    at com.xyz.validateUserLogin(SomeCommon.java:89)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

So the above exception is what is only seen .
Surprisingly on shutting down weblogic - we get additional details in the log which is pasted below : ( complete log )

```
<23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000388> <JVM 
called the WebLogic Server shutdown hook. The server will force shutdown 
now.>
<23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000396> <Server 
shutdown has been requested by <WLS Kernel>.>
 <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server 
 state changed to FORCE_SUSPENDING.>
 <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server 
 state changed to ADMIN.>
 <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server 
 state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.>
 <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
 "Default[7]", listening on fe80:0:0:0:515e:8ad6:9c96:b298:7001, was shut 
  down.>
  <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
  "Default[6]", listening on fe80:0:0:0:9857:44d:606c:9ebd:7001, was shut 
  down.>
  <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
  "Default[5]", listening on fe80:0:0:0:162:e6b1:5031:79e5:7001, was shut 
   down.>
   <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
   "Default[1]", listening on 172.26.11.12:7001, was shut down.>
   <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
   "Default[4]", listening on fe80:0:0:0:f4a9:ad8e:35cf:ad32:7001, was shut 
    down.>
    <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
    "Default[2]", listening on fe80:0:0:0:2154:84d6:eba1:3618:7001, was shut 
    down.>
    <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
    "Default[3]", listening on fe80:0:0:0:2562:eb0f:7c68:7a63:7001, was shut 
     down.>
    <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
    "Default", listening on 192.168.56.1:7001, was shut down.>
    <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
    "Default[9]", listening on 127.0.0.1:7001, was shut down.>
    <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
    "Default[10]", listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7001, was shut down.>
    <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002607> <Channel 
    "Default[8]", listening on fe80:0:0:0:dc3e:fba8:561c:e9ca:7001, was shut 
    down.>
    <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000381> 
    <ServerLifeCycle operation failed.
     Message: halt call on RuntimeServerService failed
     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     at weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream.<clinit>(IIOPOutputStream.java:138)
     at weblogic.iiop.Message.getOutputStream(Message.java:175)
     at weblogic.iiop.LocateRequestMessage.<init> 
     (LocateRequestMessage.java:93)
     at weblogic.iiop.IORManager.locateNameService(IORManager.java:196)
     at weblogic.iiop.IORManager.createInitialReference(IORManager.java:120)
     Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
     Caused By: org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: Cannot instantiate 
     com.ibm.ws.orb.WSUtilDelegateImpl  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  
    completed: No
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.createDelegate(Util.java:355)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:67)
    at weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream.<clinit>(IIOPOutputStream.java:138)
    at weblogic.iiop.Message.getOutputStream(Message.java:175)
    at weblogic.iiop.LocateRequestMessage.<init> 
    (LocateRequestMessage.java:93)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    com.ibm.ws.orb.WSUtilDelegateImpl (no security manager: RMI class loader 
    disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:393)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:185)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:219)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:152)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    >
   <23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000381> 
   <ServerLifeCycle operation failed.
   Message: halt call on EditServerService failed
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
  weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
  weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream
    at weblogic.iiop.Message.getOutputStream(Message.java:175)
    at weblogic.iiop.LocateRequestMessage.<init> 
 (LocateRequestMessage.java:93)
    at weblogic.iiop.IORManager.locateNameService(IORManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.iiop.IORManager.createInitialReference(IORManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.corba.orb.ORB.string_to_object(ORB.java:341)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
    >
<23/05/2019 10:49:25 AM EST> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000381> <ServerLifeCycle operation failed.

Message: halt call on DomainRuntimeServerService failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.iiop.IIOPOutputStream
        at weblogic.iiop.Message.getOutputStream(Message.java:175)
        at weblogic.iiop.LocateRequestMessage.<init>(LocateRequestMessage.java:93)
        at weblogic.iiop.IORManager.locateNameService(IORManager.java:196)
        at weblogic.iiop.IORManager.createInitialReference(IORManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.corba.orb.ORB.string_to_object(ORB.java:341)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

The class not found exception that weblogic is complaining about : **WsnInitialContextFactory** is present in the jar file which is within web-inf\lib

Have double checked it .
NOTE - the classes com.xyz.ServiceFactory too are present in a different jar which too is in web-inf\lib.

so classes from web-inf\lib are getting found and invoked but when the code hits the class : 'WsnInitialContextFactory ' we run into ClassNotFoundException.

NOTE2:
The other thing to note is that prior to the above call being made I am explicitly setting the following line of code:

```
System.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
```

NOTE3:
if I place these jars on a global classpath via weblogic startup script - then I dont encounter this issue:

```
set JAVA_PROPERTIES=%JAVA_PROPERTIES% -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\rmi_ibm_jars
```

I do not want to place them on the global classpath since it is not advisable and not recommended.

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace plz ? I think WebLogic needs the class com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory but is not able to load it from your web app because it has no acces to it from its own classloader. That could explain why your code works when the class is in the server's classpath.

Comment: have updated with complete stacktrace - get most of the stack trace on shutting down weblogic.